# Unable to compile Mesos frameworks

Tags: build, mesos

I have installed Mesos from source and am able to start master and slave.
But when I tried to compile `test_framework.cpp`, I get

```
error: #error regenerate this file with a newer version of protoc.
#error regenerate this file with a newer version of protoc.
```

Although, I have installed the latest version(2.6.1) from source.

Note: There were no prexisting protoc.so files on the machine.

Answer (score 2):

it seems like a protobuf version compactibility issue. Could you try on an older protobuf version (e.g., 2.5)? And configure mesos using `--with-protobuf=/path/to/libproto`.

BTW, I saw this here occasionally. Usually, most of people would prefer asking mesos related questions on mesos user mailing list (user@mesos.apache.org), which may be seen by more users and more possibly to get help:)